# Am I using the incorrect regex string for <u> tags?

Tags: php, regex

I have used [this php regex generator](https://www.phpliveregex.com/) to try and generate a regex string to find `<u>` tags in my content. The code below works for my other `preg_match_all` functions, but not for the u tags. Am I using the wrong string?

I have also tried:

`#<\s*?u\b[^>]*>(.*?)</u\b[^>]*>#s`

`<u\s[^>]*([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/u>`

```
$post_id = 122232;
$content_post = get_post($post_id);
$content = $content_post->post_content;

    if(preg_match_all("<u>(.*)</u>", $content, $matches)) {
        foreach ($matches[0] as $match){
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($match);
        echo '</pre>';
```

To add some more info: I am trying to filter the `$content` using `preg_match_all` and looking for all the `<u>` tags and its content. I am then planning to remove the tags and only display the content.

For example:

```
<p>hey my name is <u>Remco</u></p>
```

will become

```
<p>hey my name is Remco</p>
```

Update:

As suggested by Toto in the comments, this solved my problem:

`preg_replace('~</?u>~', '', $content);`

Comment: What is the input? What do you get? What do you expect?

Comment: In general case, *don't* use regex on HTML/XML

Comment: Tags alone or with their contents? The latter shouldn't be done this way.

Comment: ah, would you suggest DomDocument for this?

Comment: Why not using simple `preg_replace('~</?u>~', '', $content);`?

Comment: @Remco Yes, use DomDocument to parse HTML.

Comment: Instead of removing the tags, why don't you just change the CSS for `u` to remove the underline?

Comment: @Toto that was beautiful and exactly what I needed. `$content = preg_replace('~</?u>~', '', $content);` Thanks!

Comment: I appreciate the comments about DomDocument and I'm going to have a look at that too for the future - thanks everyone.

Comment: The obvious problem that I see is that your regular expression is not delimited. Typically the first and last character are `/` but you can really use any character as long as they match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just remove all the `<u>` tags, a simple

```
preg_replace('~</?u>~', '', $content);
```

will do the job.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed - and using `preg_replace` instead of `preg_match` makes more sense too. Thanks.